# Numpy indirect indexing

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm trying to perform aggregation functions on one or multiple arrays by using another array which contains the indices. These indices could contain duplicates which need to be dealt with depending on the aggregation function (I'm interested in a general way to do this "indirect indexing", so I hope I don't need to differentiate aggregation functions).

For instance, assume we want to obtain a sum *w* from the elements in *v* by the index in *ix*.

```
ix = [  0,   7,   0,   1,   7,   3,   0,   2,   2, 5, 6, 4]
v =  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 0, 0, 0]
```

=>

```
#       0                  1               2    3  4  5  6  7
w = [1100 (100+300+700), 400, 1700 (800+900), 600, 0, 0, 0, 700 (200+500)]
```

`sum` might be an easy one, but for instance a weighted average would be trickier (multiplication of *v<sub>1</sub>* and *v<sub>2</sub>* before collapsing into *w*). Is there an array/numpy way for doing this?

Comment: If your indices are as continuous/small as in your example, you may use `bincount(ix, v)`.

Comment: your weight on 2, 3 index seems not correct. Or I misunderstand your question?

Comment: oops - thanks @shtse8. see corrected corrected _w_.

Comment: how big are your arrays/does performance matter?

Comment: @anon01, I wouldn't ask if performance wouldn't matter (I also wouldn't use numpy if performance wouldn't matter). The array is in the thousands, but this code is called as often as possible per time unit.

Comment: asking because the scale determines what the best tool for the job is

Comment: as fast as possible (while staying in Python land, of course) ;-)

Comment: please see my answer below.  numpy can be faster than pandas but apparently doesn't have a `groupby` operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast numpy method:

```
In [107]: ix = np.array([  0,   7,   0,   1,   7,   3,   0,   2,   2, 5, 6, 4])
     ...: v =  np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 0, 0, 0])
In [108]: 
In [108]: np.bincount(ix,v)
Out[108]: array([1100.,  400., 1700.,  600.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  700.])
```

another, not quite as fast, but potentially more flexible (using other `ufunc`):

```
In [119]: a = np.zeros(8,int)
     ...: np.add.at(a, ix,v)
     ...: a
     ...: 
     ...: 
Out[119]: array([1100,  400, 1700,  600,    0,    0,    0,  700])
```

---

Timings on this small example:

```
In [121]: timeit [np.sum(v[ix == [x]]) for x in range(ix.max() + 1)]
159 µs ± 311 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [122]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(ix, v), columns=["idx", "v"])
     ...: w = df.groupby(df.idx).v.sum().to_numpy()
1.48 ms ± 884 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [123]: timeit np.bincount(ix,v)
2.15 µs ± 6.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [124]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.zeros(8,int)
     ...: np.add.at(a, ix,v)
     ...: a
9.4 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: `np.add.at` is exactly what I was looking for (and there's a wealth of other `ufuncs` that I can source from too) and it runs blazing fast - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
[np.sum(v[ix == [x]]) for x in range(ix.max() + 1)]
```

Result:

```
[1100  400 1700  600    0    0    0  700]
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
  <code data-type="sample-code">
import numpy as np
ix = np.array([0, 7, 0, 1, 7, 3, 0, 2, 2, 5, 6, 4])
v = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 0, 0, 0])

print([np.sum(v[ix == [x]]) for x in range(ix.max() + 1)])
  </code>
</div>
```

Comment: _v_ might be large ish, so a list comprehension might be utterly slow (hence the question for a array/numpy way of accomplishing this)...

Comment: ~1k shouldn't go to 1M, but called many times. the more calls per time unit, the better.

Comment: In my tests, this comprehension scales linearly, but so does the `pandas.groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking a `groupby` operation.  Pandas has a pretty extensive api for this kind of thing and wraps numpy under the hood so you get vectorization (as fast as numpy with some operations).  Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
ix = [  0,   7,   0,   1,   7,   3,   0,   2,   2, 5, 6, 4]
v =  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(ix, v), columns=["idx", "v"])

# groupby the index, apply a sum function, convert type to numpy:
# array([1100,  400, 1700,  600,    0,    0,    0,  700])
w = df.groupby(df.idx).v.sum().to_numpy()
```

You can do more sophisticated calculations and use overloaded arithemtic operations for convenience:

```
df["weights"] = np.random.rand(len(df))
df["weights"].mul(df["v"]).groupby("idx").sum()
```

And it is generally performant:

```
n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({"idx": np.random.choice(10, n), "v": np.random.rand(n)})

%timeit df.groupby("idx")["v"].sum()
# 11.7 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As a demonstration of versatility: you can apply more exotic functions, such as the harmonic mean to each group (`apply` is a little slower):

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import hmean
%timeit df.groupby("idx").apply(hmean)
# 51.3 ms ± 1.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
idx
0    0.083368
1    0.049457
2    0.077801
3    0.074263
4    0.065142
5    0.035001
6    0.080105
7    0.002465
8    0.076336
9    0.036461
```

or a custom function:

```
def my_func(rows):
     return np.max(rows)/np.min(rows)

%timeit df.groupby("idx")["v"].apply(my_func)
# 46.6 ms ± 2.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
idx
0    8.265517e+04
1    8.900603e+05
2    1.874362e+05
3    1.419228e+05
4    4.722633e+05
5    1.382114e+06
6    1.000876e+05
7    3.939510e+07
8    7.747462e+04
9    8.919914e+05
```

Comment: While `pandas` does have powerful `groupby` functionality, I'm not sure it's fast.  `numpy` doesn't have any equivalents, so it can't depend on `numpy` for speed.  The list comprehension in the other answer is 10x faster than your example (the combined `df` and `w` calcs).  I don't know how scaling.

Comment: That's not really true. For 1m rows in the case of groupby + arithmetic sum, the pandas soln is faster than a comprehension over np.arrays by more than 2x on my machine.  Numpy does't have gropuby, but we're only splitting into 10 groups; within each numpy can do its SIMD magic.

Comment: the reason I posted this over `bincount` (which is ~`n_bins` times faster), is because the poster specifically requested something more flexible